# Cambiar el idioma de SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java

Necesito un String que me de como resultado un formato de fecha mas o menos así "dd 'de' MMMM 'de' yyyy", para que me de como resultado por ejemplo 13 de julio de 2022, sin embargo el nombre del mes se sale en inglés

mi código es este:

```
   Date f = new Date();
   SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd 'de' MMMM 'de' yyyy");
   System.out.println(df.format(f));
```

la salida de la consola me sale así:

13 de July de 2022

El idioma de mi sistema está en español Latinoamericano, puedo hardcodear el nombre del mes para resolver el problema, pero lo que necesito es encontrar la forma correcta de implementar SimpleDateFormat

Agradezco a esta valiosa comunidad y todos los aportes que me puedan dar.

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` tiene un constructor que acepta dos parámetros... un `String` y un `Locale`, probaste a usarlo??

Comment: Locale.getDefault() da los valores en el idioma que tenga el dispositivo,,**SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd 'de' MMMM 'de' yyyy",Locale.getDefault());**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues usas un Locale

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
String formatted = dateFormat.format(alguna_fecha_que_quieras_dar_formato);
```